# Why does constraint fail when upsert used in conjunction with triggers?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Please could someone explain why this unique constraint fails and if there is any workaround or suggestions.

With this schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE abc 
(
    a INTEGER NOT NULL,
    b INTEGER NOT NULL,
    c INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_a_b ON abc(a, b);

CREATE TABLE xyz 
(
    x INTEGER NOT NULL,
    y INTEGER NOT NULL,
    z INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_x_y ON xyz(x, y);
```

I have triggers on a table `xyz` for both insert and update operations, they both perform insert or replace on table `abc` which has a unique index.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER on_insert_xyz
AFTER INSERT 
ON xyz
BEGIN
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO abc(a, b, c)
    SELECT * FROM xyz LIMIT 1;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER on_update_xyz
AFTER UPDATE 
ON xyz
BEGIN
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO abc(a, b, c)
    SELECT * FROM xyz LIMIT 1;
END;
```

I have an upsert statement on table `xyz`that causes the triggers to execute. If the upsert statement causes the update trigger to execute, then the unique index constraint fails on table `abc`.

```sql
INSERT INTO xyz(x, y, z) VALUES(1, 2, 3) ON CONFLICT(x, y) DO UPDATE SET z = excluded.z -- Works;
INSERT INTO xyz(x, y, z) VALUES(1, 2, 4) ON CONFLICT(x, y) DO UPDATE SET z = excluded.z -- Fails;
```

> UNIQUE constraint failed: abc.a, abc.b

Comment: Did you find a way to get around this? I'm currently facing the same issue with my own database.